# Can an unregistered e-filer pay using a deposit account?

Tags: payment

I've had trouble with the credit card payment interface in the past, hence this question.

I'd expect the answer to be yes, but I'm also somewhat wondering how the USPTO controls access to the deposit accounts - what would stop someone from charging a random account as an unregistered e-filer?

Answer (score 0):

Registration is not required to open a deposit account but you will need at least $1,000 in it on the last day of every month.

I do not think the USPTO has major problems with deposit account fraud.